# JitterBufferDelay spikes during a video stream change

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer

I'm facing an interesting behaviour in WebRTC that im hoping someone can point out.

I have a simple chrome app that is connected a GStreamer backend that is basically an audio/video mixer. There are no stream changes on the client side, only on the remote side. I.e, there is only ever one video stream being sent to the client.

When the app is receiving only its own remote PIP view with a black background, the JitterBufferDelay is low (40 ms or so).

When another video stream is fed into the compositor in the backend and that stream fills the black background, I see a spike in JitterBufferDelay that goes to 800 ms, after which is reduces overtime to a flat value that is still above where it was before (probably around 100 ms).

Jitter is flat for the whole duration of the call. What can be causing the JitterBufferDelay to spike when another video stream is added?

Example (this time it didnt quite reach 800 but it can and sometimes also reaches 1200)

[image]

To recap:

1. Only PIP is rendered (40 ms JB delay - single video stream)
2. Another video is added to the compositor (still a single video stream, however this time the JB delay climbs to 800 before slowly retracing back to a flat value).
3. Higher flat value is maintained.

Comment: If I had to guess an answer to my own question, I'd guess that its the additional audio stream that is causing the delay. When its only the PIP, there is no audio. When another video stream is added, audio begins to flow to the WebRTC app. It could be delayed, and thus causes the JB to delay video in order to AV synchronize. I don't know how to verify this though.